# How to store user's interest in the drupal profile2?

Tags: drupal, profile, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I want to use Drupal profile2 to store the user's preference, one key preference is to store the user's interest, which is a group of tags he interests

for example, there are a few content tags (tag1, tag2, tag3), and I add tag1 into my preference. then the system could recommend some content based on the interest tags I choose.

Well, I installed profile2, and make a new category, and also make a field in the category, the field 's type is taxonomy. When it is done, I don't what to do next? how to add it to profile, make a form?? I still have no idea, and not so familiar with form

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  // create profile object
  $profile = profile_create(array('user' => $account, 'type' => 'main'));

  // populate profile fields
  $profile->field_firstname['und'][0]['value'] = 'John';
  $profile->field_lastname['und'][0]['value'] = 'Smith';
  $profile->field_gender['und'][0]['value'] = 'M';

  // save profile
  profile2_save($profile);
?>
```

Found this on http://drupal.org/node/1185912#comment-4590496 Hope it helps you.